# PHP's $_POST doesn't like how I post

Tags: php, javascript

As everyone knows, PHP has a `$_POST` variable that stores data from POST requests.

I'm trying to use it with XHR..

```
xhr.send('hey=hello&hi=there');
```

..but it doesn't work..

```
echo $_POST['hey'] . ' ' . $_POST['hi']; # The page should say "hello there", but it doesn't.
```

Am I sending the data incorrectly?

Do I need to change my php.ini?

How do I get this to work? :(

Comment: Have you looked at firebug what exact request is performed?

Comment: Make sure that whatever `xhr.send` is, is actually sending it in POST mode.

Comment: @zerkms No, because I use Chrome. ;)

Comment: @Renesis I've checked the request dozens of times and it is using the POST method.

Comment: @tylermwashburn: `ctrl+shift+I` then ;-) Btw, what `file_get_contents('php://input');` gives to you?

Comment: @tylserwashburn, use Fiddler, it is far more universal.  http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: @Brad I'm using Mac OS 10.6, so.. And the request is working fine, it's PHP that's being problematic.

Comment: @tylerwashburn, I highly doubt it.  I'm quite certain the problem is with your request.

Comment: @Brad I'm quite certain it's not. Check the answer.

Comment: @tylermwashburn, happy you figured it out!  Looks like the problem was with how you were making the request...

Comment: @Brad The problem was just a missing request header. That's it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that you're not sending the request with a `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so it's getting treated as an unknown chunk of data rather than a set of URL-encoded key/value pairs.

Comment: So should `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-urlencoded');` fix it?

Comment: @tyler I made a mistake in writing out the content-type value. Try again with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` please.